# Nonparametric estimation of standard error on large samples

Tags: nonparametric, bootstrap, standard-error, large-data

The bootstrap seems to be the gold standard for attaching a standard error to a point estimate on a sample. However, if the sample size is very large, it can be prohibitively expensive to repeat the point estimate for >50 times, as required by the bootstrap technique.

Is there a cheaper alternative, potentially leveraging the fact that the sample is very large?

Comment: It depends on the point estimator. For instance, by exploiting some linear algebraic identities, a jackknife estimator of OLS parameter estimates is efficient no matter how many observations are available, because the estimate can be quickly *updated* based only on knowing which observation was removed from the dataset.  Could you therefore tell us more about your particular situation?

Comment: In this particular case, I'm computing precision and recall for a ML model, so the estimator is a rational function of sample averages. But I've encountered this problem many times in the past, and hacked my way through it. This time, I wanted to learn some principled general solutions.

Comment: Parallel processing, CUDA/GPU... All of the bootstrap resamples can be performed in parallel.

Comment: Yes, the computation is trivially parallel, so the time can be brought down easily, but the $$ cost will stay the same.